# How to retrieve values from Room, when creating the ViewModel instance

Tags: android, mvvm

I have MVVM fragment with this simple requirement.

The fragment have a EntryText field, and I want to populate with a value calculated in the view model,
when the viewmodel is created I need to call a Room request and get a value, then that value should be present to the user, and the user can change that value.

Also I'm soring that value in the State Handle

```
var parcelaDesde = state.get<String>("parcelaDesde")?:"0"
    set(value) {
        field = value
        state.set("parcelaDesde", value)
    }
```

I resolved with:

*creating a public methos in viewmodel that retrieve info from Room and update local member field, also update a MutableLiveData that is observed in Fragment

```
fun updateParcelaDesde(default: Int) {
    val num = parcelaDesde.toIntOrNull()
    num?.let {
        if (it == default) {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                parcelaDesde = filialcruzaRepository.getMinNroParcela(filial.value?.id!!)?.toString()?:"0"
                Log.d(TAG, "updateParcelaDesde: $parcelaDesde")
                isLoadingDesde.postValue(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on the Fragment, I just observe the liveData and update the UI when te loading is completed.

```
    viewModel.isLoadingDesde.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        binding.etParcelaDesde.setText( viewModel.parcelaDesde.trim() )
    }
```

Is this the correct way ?
How to do this if I want to us dataBinding?

Best Regards

Comment: Did you get a chance to [read the documenation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata)? It tells you how to integrate user input into your repository requests.

Comment: mm.. Thanks, but is not exactly my use case, I want a dynamic default value to be gotten from local database, the default value is no the same, let's say is the last (max) invoice number in a invoices table... each time could be different.